# How can I use `await fetch()` in a promise so that it doesn't violate `no-async-promise-executor`?

Tags: javascript, eslint

My code is violating the eslint rule [no-async-promise-executor](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-async-promise-executor) but I'm not sure how to refactor it so that it doesn't have the `async` in the `new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {});` statement.  My code is full of these and I guess it causes errors to not be caught by the compiler. I could use some help understanding this question better

Here's an example function:

```
updateUser = () => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const url = "/getUser";
            const response = await fetch(url);
            if (response.ok) {
                const user = await response.json();
                //
                // Do something with user object...
                //
            } else {
                console.log("response", response);
                window.location = "/admin";
            }
            resolve();
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("error: ", error);
            reject(error);
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

when you mark the function as async, it will automatically wrap the return value inside a promise, whatever you return from the function... it will get passed to .then() and whatever is thrown inside a async function will get passed to your error handler such as .catch()

here is a example of what you could do.

```
const updateUser = async () => {
    const url = "/getUser";
    let response;

    try {
        response = await fetch(url);
    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error(error);
    }

    return response;
}
```

you can also reference the global promise explicit to return or reject values inside a async function.

```
const updateUser = async () => {
    const url = "/getUser";
    let response;

    try {
        response = await fetch(url);
    } catch (error) {
        Promise.reject(error);
    }

    return Promise.resolve(response);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I'm still trying to wrap my head around this because apparently, I've been using promises all wrong! :)  Using your first example, would I still call `await updateUser();`?  Also, can you explain why I would use `Promise.reject(error);` and `Promise.resolve(response);` from your second example?

Comment: You can await the async function, async function will return a promise.  Whatever you return inside an async function... That value will get wrapped in ```Promise.resolve()```. However if you are inside a call back you wont be returning from the promise but the nested call back instead, i hope this example helps. ```const asyncFunc = async () => {
    fs.readFile(path, (err, data) => {
        return data;
    }) // wrong

    fs.readFile(path, (err, data) => {
        Promise.resolve(data);
    }) // wrong
}```

Comment: hey i made a typo in my code snippet here we go! ```const asyncFunc = async () => {
    fs.readFile(path, (err, data) => { return data; }); // wrong 
    fs.readFile(path, (err, data) => { Promise.resolve(data); }) // right
}
```

Comment: One last question (I hope).  Using your first example, I still call updateUser like this: `await updateUser();` right?  And if I don't include the `await` it will still work but not wait for it to complete before continuing.  Right?

Comment: yes exactly. if no await is used the execution is not paused and your code will then be executed synchronously. You wont be able to guarantee when the function will complete.

Answer (score 1):

`async` functions always return promises.

By wrapping your anonymous `async` function in `new Promise(...)` you are creating a Promise which only and always adopts the promise returned by the async function.

Just get rid of the wrapper, replace your `resolve` calls with `return` and your `reject` with `throw`.

```
updateUser = async () => {
    try {
        const url = "/getUser";
        const response = await fetch(url);
        if (response.ok) {
            const user = await response.json();
            //
            // Do something with user object...
            //
        } else {
            console.log("response", response);
            window.location = "/admin";
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("error: ", error);
        throw error;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks!  Just so that I make sure I understand this.  I was calling `await  updateUser();`.  Can I still do that?

Comment: @Dev01 — Why wouldn't you be able to do that?

Comment: I don't know.  I'm just trying to understand it.  If I add `return response;` right before the `catch(error)` line, and then call `const result = await updateUser();`, would `result` receive the `response` object?  I know this is probably trivial but I guess I've been using promises wrong.  In general, is there any reason to use `return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {}) ` except for some very special cases?

Comment: Yes. And yes: Whenever you need to create a promise from something asynchronous and non-promise based.

Comment: Awesome!  This is going to make my code much cleaner, I have promises everywhere right now.  :/  Can you give me an example of when you would use `return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {})`?